# How can I mark it up?

Tags: html, css, markup

I have a picture and it looks like this: 
[image]

And I want to mark it up with HTML and CSS.

I want curved part to be always at the center of screen and have content.
And I want flat parts to stretch depending on user screen width by sides.

How can I do it? Could anyone provide me examples?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Depending on whether the size of the middle is static, I could see this done with 3 elements, spanning 100% of the screen. While you could use actual images (with the left and right sides merely thin strips repeated as backgrounds). a little research on `border-radius`, `linear-gradient`, and `box-shadow` might start you in the right direction. A three column table, with 100% width, with a specific width defined (in px) to the center `td` is one, but not the only way to approach this...

Comment: The size of the middle is static, yes. I'll use images, but I don't want use tables, is there CSS way?

Comment: Sure, you need a Fluid Layout with a Fixed Column in the Middle. Are you using any CSS Frameworks?

Comment: This is about as close as I can get...

http://jsfiddle.net/rLDHG/        

As I'm more experienced with tables, I fell short of centering the inner arch div... : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/KcP5k/41/)**

html

```
#test{
    width: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px) rotate(90deg) ;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
}

#test:after{
    background: white;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px / 600px 0 0  600px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
}
```

---

So here is the final **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/KcP5k/42/)** as required

html

```
<div id="testbefore"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
#testbefore {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
#test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:top;
}
#test:after {
    background: white;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px / 600px 0 0 600px;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, but side lines don't stretch. How to implement it?

Comment: checkout the edited demo.